# How to create .jsp file in android studio and upload the project in github from android studio

Tags: github, android-studio

I want to create .jsp file in my android studio project and I want to upload my project to GitHub. For doing those 2 issues, what should I do in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Here, there is a tutorial with screenshots that will help you initialize a git repo using android studio:
http://wii.logdown.com/posts/2013/11/15/android-studio-git-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA and .jsp files are supported by IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition.So you'll need that.